# How to Update many elements in mongoose array which has embedded documents

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, embedded-documents

I have this mongoose model

```
resourceId: {
    type: String,
},

resourceName: {
    type: String,
},

dateAndValue: [
    {
        date: { type: Date },
        value: { type: Number },
    },
],

project: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'project',
},
```

I want to update all value fileds of dateAndValue array elemets to "0" of a given resourceId, given project within a given date range!

```
await QuantumResourcesManpowerAdmin.updateMany(
    {
        project,
        resourceId,
        'dateAndValue.date': { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'dateAndValue.$.value': 0,
        },
    },
    { upsert: true }
);
res.status(200).json({ success: true });
```

This is the code I used for it. It returns success but does not do any update.
All inputs are correct, something is wrong with only the updateMany query, all other functions work!

Answer (score 0):

```
await QuantumResourcesManpowerAdmin.updateMany(
    {
        project,
        resourceId,
        'dateAndValue.date': { $gte: startDate, $lte: endDate },
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'dateAndValue.$[element].value': 0,
        },
    },
 {arrayFilters:[{'element.date':{$gte: startDate, $lte: endDate }}] ,upsert: true }
);
res.status(200).json({ success: true });
```

Comment: 'dateAndValue.$[ ].value':0

Comment: This Code updates the whole array, But I want to update only within given date range